Flare stars and habitability
I wanted to make a star that is a red dwarf, but it is a flare star, as it goes through random increments in brightness by a factor of 2. If the star mostly flares on a 70° inclination, and my hypothetical planet orbits in the star's equator, will the planet be spared from radiation? If it would still get excessive radiation, what could I tweak to make the flare star flare randomly, but less intense that it would be habitable?

I like this idea. Why are you worried about exact science? Per the [help/on-topic], we're here to help you build an imaginary world. That means rationalizing things to help with believability, not perfecting science. I think you've already done a great job of rationalizing the habitability of your world. Cheers.

To the best of our current scientific knowledge ALL red dwarfs are 'flare' stars. I.E. your problem is that in a hard SF universe you can't arbitrarily decide what angles flares will be expelled at. You've basically got a scenario where a drunken cowboy is staggering around a camp fire firing random pot shots out into the air and a mouse is running in circles around the camp fire! Yes. Eventfully he'll score a hit. But the odds are not great. Witness Earth and its (relatively) stable Star. How many times has Earth  been hit by significant solar flares?

How about having a tidally-locked planet?
Life often evolves at boundaries, such as the seashore, black smokers on the sea bottom, pools, and things like that. A tidally locked planet will have a boundry between the light and the dark side. This will not be fixed as the planet will wobble about a mean position just as the moon does, so this boundary zone might be quite broad. Every hill would have a sunny side which would be hit by the flares, and a sheltered side. Water and even air might condense on the cold side. If a flare strips part of the atmosphere, that might be replaced in the short term from evaporation on the cold side.
What sort of life would thrive? The obvious answer would be something that could go dormant to survive times of extreme hot and cold. This might lead to some extreme forms that chose to live in the more extreme regions to avoid predators.

Interesting! That seems like a cool idea!

This is taking Drake's equation and chucking away a lot of familiar constants and grabbing random other values. It could be more likely that basic life evolves, but perhaps doesn't get to flying saucers and ray guns. We know red dwarfs last a long time, and some of them flare, but don't really know much about the average red dwarf, and we don't know anything about tidally locked Goldilocks planets. Plenty of elbow room for writing fiction.

Make your planet big with lots of atmosphere and a very powerful magnetic field.
Note that your aliens will be adapted to very high pressure life and will remain stuck on the surface.  A world that could survive the flares is a world where chemical rockets can't reach orbit and your aliens probably need to travel in big, thick pressure vessels.  You also have issues with the atmosphere being a supercritical fluid.

I was considering adding a Mini-Neptune planet that is hycean because why not lol. Thanks for the suggestions.
